# Installing Canon Pixma mg2400-series printer drivers on Manjaro/Arch?

Tags: drivers, manjaro, printer, canon, aur

The drivers for this printer are provided as source, deb and rpm packages on the [Canon website](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/mg2440.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20%2864-bit%29). I have already tested the deb files and they work on the same machine.

Because I knew about them, I was able to identify them in AUR using Pamac. They are:

`cnijfilter-common-mg2400` - https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/cnijfilter-common-mg2400 and
`cnijfilter-mg2400series` - https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/cnijfilter-mg2400series

I get this error when trying to install with pamac or yaourt:

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
cnijfilter-common-mg2400: /usr/lib64 exists in filesystem
```

Also:

```
pacman -Qo /usr/lib64
/usr/lib64 is owned by filesystem 2015.09-1
```

`/usr/lib64` is a link to `/usr/lib`, a 3.2 GB directory containing many program folders.

What should I do?

---

Using `deb2targz` I have been able to extract from the `deb` files some folders. But what should I do with them?

---

### UPDATE

AUR package maintainer has [updated the mg2400 AUR packages](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=27569.msg231192#msg231192).

See comments by Rob and Oberon under that topic on the reasons why the previous packages didn't work.

---

But for whatever reason the printer doesn't work.

In Ubuntu, the drivers once installed, the printer was already present in the list of printers. Here it is not, and after adding it would not print.

Although the drivers seem to me exactly the same two packages that were enough to make the printer work in ubuntu-based systems, they are not enough in Manjaro. Some other package is needed or most probably some application needs to be started for the printer to work, although I started cups and added to startup with

```
sudo systemctl start org.cups.cupsd

sudo systemctl enable org.cups.cupsd
```

[image]

The error is when selecting "Print self-test page." Selecting "Print test page" sends the job to printer with no result, just like when trying to print any file.

I also checked and can confirm that the device URI shows the same line as in Linux Mint (same computer, same printer).

Only the driver has a slightly different description - in Manjaro:  Canon MG2400 series Ver.4.00, in Mint: Canon MG2400 series - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.10-pre2.

Comment: I don't know anything about Arch, but it sounds like your package should not contain `/usr/lib64`. Does it? And if so, can you remove it, and rebuild?

Comment: @FaheemMitha - Indeed. See my update with a link to a Manjaro post. I think I'll wait and see if the maintainer will respond, maybe fix the package. He is a Manjaro guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In Manjaro 15.09

(stable realease at the post date of the question)

Short answer: **`gutenprint` package needs to be installed too**

`sudo pacman -S gutenprint`

that of course beside the two updated AUR packages of the Canon 2400series driver: the links for those are in the question. Activate AUR sources in Pamac, or use yaourt etc to install them.

---

As seen in the last part of the updated question, the same printer installed in Linux Mint KDE in multi-boot on the same machine had a different driver specification.

In Manjaro: Canon MG2400 series Ver.4.00, in Mint: Canon MG2400 series - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.10-pre2.

Checking `gutenprint` in Pamac, it was not installed. After installing it and adding the printer again, also starting cups as presented in the question, the printer worked.

---

Canon Pixma MG2450 is also a scanner: the driver for that is `scangearmp-common` also in AUR.

---

### In Manjaro 16.10.2:

Beside `cnijfilter-common-mg24001`, `cnijfilter-mg2400series` and `gutenprint`, be sure these packages are also installed:

```
foomatic-db-gutenprint
foomatic-db-gutenprint-ppds
foomatic-db
foomatic-db-engine
```

As for scanning, in Manjaro 16.10.2, the package `scangearmp-common` is no longer needed: `simple-scan` is enough.

On the new Manjaro forum [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cannot-print-with-canon-pixma-mg2400series-in-16-10-2-fringilla-xfce-after-installing-the-drivers/13723).

---

### In Manjaro 17.0:

The 'Print Settings' application (GUI to add printer) was missing in my Xfce 17 stable version. To install it:

```
sudo pacman -Sy manjaro-printer
```